# Swift Compiler: cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject]' with an index of type '()'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, swift-playground

**Scenario:**

STEP 1: 
[image: Error]
STEP 2:
[image: included_print_no_error]
STEP 3:
[image: removed_print_no_error]
**Problem Summarized:**
I started working with swift and its basic concepts. 
First, I tried making an array `ab` with multiple different typed elements (not sure if it should be called an array). Then I tried to test an index value `ab[2]`.

After testing an index value successfully, I made a dictionary `dictAbc` where I used different indices `ab[4]` `ab[6]` pointing to its keys. It introduced an error as mentioned in STEP 1.

I tried capping `ab[2]` into a print function as mentioned in STEP 2, it removed the error

Then I removed print method and made STEP 3 code same as STEP 1, it doesn't produce any error now.

Code:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

var num: Float64 = 4.00000000000000000000000000

print("\(num)")

let a = "Hello"
let b = 12786
let c = a + String(b)


var ab = [1221, 123123, 123123,123123,"asdasd", "adasdasd",      1263781.123]
ab[2]
var dictAbc = ["hello":ab[4], "let":ab[6]]
dictAbc["let"]
```

**Project Navigator Screenshot**

[image: Project Navigator]

*Note: Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220)*

***Is something wrong with Playground compiler?***

Comment: Please include the code in your question, not just screenshots.

Comment: @EricD.:Thanks for suggestion, did it..

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: what's your observation, did you get the error once or didn't get it at all! Please check the EDIT 2 too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of how a Playground works: it tries to evaluate *every* expression as soon as you've finished typing.

So when you type this quickly:

```
ab[1]
```

No errors, but if you take your time and pause with the cursor inside the brackets:

```
ab[]
```

you will indeed get the `cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject]' with an index of type '()'` error, but this is only a **temporary** error message due to the "real-time" nature of the Playground.

If the error is still there after having typed the index number, then to make it disappear you just have to "wake up" the Playground by adding an empty line somewhere, adding a space after the expression, or adding other code, of course. The Playground will then re-evaluate everything and will remove the false error.